# zsh specify more than one character for pattern substitution

Tags: zsh

This

```
print Contact\ us,\ Blog/(:l:gs/ /-)
```

results in this:

```
contact-us,-blog
```

How to change that `,` too.

I tried:

```
print Contact\ us,\ Blog/(:l:gs/ ,/-)
print Contact\ us,\ Blog/(:l:gs/[ ,]/-)
```

without success.

EDIT:
I see it uses character sequence as a string to replace, so no pattern here.
Is there any better way than using multiple `:gs` in a sequence, and without using external commands like `sed` of course?

Comment: Are you sure `print Contact\ us,\ Blog/(:l:gs/ /-)` is even valid zsh code? Colon modifiers can only be used in history expansion, parameter expansion, and filename generation, and you appear to be using none of the above. If you are trying to do parameter expansion, then the syntax would be `s="Contact us, Blog" && print ${s:l:gs/ /-}`. Anyway, what you are looking for is `setopt histsubstpattern && s="Contact us, Blog" && print ${s:l:gs/[ ,]/-}`. Also `setopt localoptions` if you don't want to modify global options.

Comment: Ref: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers.

Comment: It is valid, if there is a directory named `Contact\ us,\ Blog/`.. with that `setopt` it works now!

Comment: Well yeah, I meant valid under normal conditions... Of course I wouldn't have imagined a filename like that...

Comment: Neither would I, however that's what I got from designer

Comment: At first I thought you have found some magic way of performing parameter expansion without assigning to a parameter... That would be awesome.

Comment: @4ae1e1 There is; `${:-foo}` is a default value expansion without an actual parameter, but the result can be nested as with any other expansion. For example, strip the leading `f` with `${${:-foo}#f}`.